# Can you do inline manipulation of function returns in powershell?

Tags: powershell

What I mean by that is can you have something like: `$output = Get-Date.month`. Obviously this only works when you know the return type. This would be very useful for making code more concise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Absolutely

The `.` member access operator works on any expression, not just variables:

```
$output = (Get-Date).Month
```

Answer (score 3):

[Mathias R. Jessen's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62817138/11025476) shows the usefulness and conciseness of the member access operator.

To expand further, you can cast or change the type of the output. Then use whatever method you want to access the property. Take the defined function below:

```
Function Foo {
'October 23, 2020'
}

(Foo).GetType()
IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     String                                   System.Object
```

We know the function `Foo` returns a string, which doesn't have a `Month` property. We can cast the `String` to a `DateTime` object.

```
([datetime](Foo)).GetType()
IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     DateTime                                 System.ValueType

([datetime](Foo)).Month
10

[datetime](Foo) | Select -Expand Month
10
```

You can use the `-as` operator to change the type provided it can be cast as is.

```
((Foo) -as [datetime]).Month
10
```